# python: showing only two decimal digits when tabulating a float

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

I have written a code that parses some text documents and shows the frequence in which some words appear.

The output is the following:

```
Counting words by tag
---------------------

modals
per 1000 words                    can  could  shall should   will  would
austen-emma.txt                1.480000 4.350000 1.100000 1.920000 2.900000 4.260000
austen-persuasion.txt          1.090000 4.590000 0.560000 1.920000 1.650000 3.620000
austen-sense.txt               1.500000 4.060000 0.870000 1.640000 2.500000 3.600000
chesterton-ball.txt            1.460000 1.210000 0.510000 0.770000 2.040000 1.440000
chesterton-brown.txt           1.500000 1.990000 0.350000 0.650000 1.290000 1.570000
chesterton-thursday.txt        1.760000 2.180000 0.710000 0.780000 1.570000 1.730000
```

As you can see, the numbers are rounded to hundredths, but my program still prints some excessive zeros.

That dipends on the tabulation, that is on the following code rows:

```
     cell = round(float(cfdist[fileid][w])*1000/number_of_words[fileid],2)
     print '%6f' % (cell),
```

Would someone be able to help me to improve the row print '%6f' % (cell), so that it would not show the ending zeros?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

See the [Python string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) documentation. The "%6f" is your problem. Instead, try

```
print "%.2f" % cell
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion, this works: print '%6.2f' % cell,

Answer (score 1):

num = 12.3456

new_val = '%.2f' % float(num)

print float(new_val)

12.34